# SSIS error due to "Protection level" value "encryptsensitivewithuserkey", can a pacakge have nothing sensitive?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have today ended up supporting a brand new (for me :)) package which threw below error.

"Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Property" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.

"

I got that package has been deployed with "Protection level" value "encryptsensitivewithuserkey" so ssis engine was looking for Developers user key (Windows profile) which it did not got on production machine.

As pacakge was not design fail on this error it went ahead and ended up doing it's job perfectly.

Now I am a bit confuse, the way I understand SSIS engine on production would not have been able to able to read some sensitive information which should have stopped him doing it's job.
I am not sure what properties are Sensitive (I thinks that is decided by TASK/Component author).

Just to give idea of package I have given image below.

[image]

Is there nothing Sensitive which required User Key of devloper?

I just want to clear my concept of how this works.

Comment: r u able to run the pkg using your local credentials ?

Comment: @praveen I can not try as I do not have some acesses. I was just wondering in the whole package nothing is Sensitive?

Comment: Sensitive means credentials information .From the image i could see SMTP conn manager and PCSN.... which might be storing username and password. These informations are protected by the user

Comment: @praveen may be at ran fine as it got connnection string at run time from configuration.